# Adding right-hand side column to WordPress post depending on post category

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Trying to add a right-hand column to posts to display on certain categories in WordPress. (In this instance, when posting a job vacancy under the category 'vacancies' I want a right hand column to be featuring job specs/details.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Try at [WordPress Development Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can use plugins (Category Posts Widget). Try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/screenshots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this adding some logic to `functions.php`:

Use `in_category( 'vacancies', get_the_ID() )` to determine if the current post holds the wanted category, and then use `wp_nav_menu()` to display the wanted menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Vacancies menu' );
```

Your first have to register your custom menu. See codex for details on how to do it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

The complete code would look something like:

```
<?php 
if ( is_single() && in_category( 'vacancies', get_the_ID() ) ):
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Vacancies menu' );
else:
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Standard menu' );
endif;
?>
```